# My code works with downloaded gifs, but not with the one I made, may anyone help me?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas, animated-gif

So I saw this code on YouTube, and wanted to try it, since I need animated gif in my program, I made a throwaway file to test if it works, and it works, but only on downloaded gifs. Though, I don't need downloaded one, but the one I made. I have added the gif that work as an attachment, but mine is a few KB bigger than the limit(https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sfv7d.gif).

When I added my gif in the file=".gif" line, and program was run, only the console appeared, and root wasn't visible, but with the other one, everything worked as how it should have. If it is of any help, my gif is quite large dimension wise(1600x900px).

Here is the code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image

root = tk.Tk()
file="star.gif"

info = Image.open(file)

frames = info.n_frames  # gives total number of frames that gif contains

# creating list of PhotoImage objects for each frames
im = [tk.PhotoImage(file=file,format=f"gif -index {i}") for i in range(frames)]

count = 0
anim = None
def animation(count):
    global anim
    im2 = im[count]

    gif_label.configure(image=im2)
    count += 1
    if count == frames:
        count = 0
    anim = root.after(50,lambda :animation(count))

def stop_animation():
    root.after_cancel(anim)

gif_label = tk.Label(root,image="")
gif_label.pack()

start = tk.Button(root,text="start",command=lambda :animation(count))
start.pack()

stop = tk.Button(root,text="stop",command=stop_animation)
stop.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Any help would be great, and thank you in advance!!

Here is the gif that won't work:
[Gif that doesnt work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pxy3W.gif)

Comment: How did you make the gif that doesn't work? Did you try to change various things about it, for example the size? What do you think is different about the non-working gif?

Comment: I made the gif using Photoshop, and I cannot really change its dimensions, since I need them the way they are. I am not sure what really is different between it and others, since it works 
normally when opened with image viewer

Comment: "and I cannot really change its dimensions, since I need them the way they are" You are capable of creating **a** gif with different dimensions, right? Right now, we are not solving the original problem; we are **diagnosing the code**.  "I am not sure what really is different between it and others" Well, if we are going to figure that out, then perhaps we should **try changing things about the gif** and see what does and doesn't work, right?

Comment: Did you try using `PIL.ImageTk.PhotoImage` instead of `tk.PhotoImage`?

Comment: See [mre]. You need to provide that problematic GIF file. If the file size is limited, you can fill frames with black pixels or clip only one or two frames.

Comment: So sorry for the delay in answering, I was sleeping, and then I went to school, but I am back now. I tried PIL.ImageTK.PhotoImage, it didnt work, but I will be able to add the gif here now for you to look at it, I have reduced its dimensions a bit, tried it but still the same was happening, only the console would appear, but no root window...

Comment: your gif seems to work correctly. I can see the characters bouncing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The provided *not working* GIF actually works, but it takes time to load all the frames. It takes around 70 seconds in my PC with AMD Ryzen 9 CPU.

It is a lot faster if using `Pillow` module:

```py
...
from PIL import Image, ImageTk, ImageSequence
...
im = [ImageTk.PhotoImage(img) for img in ImageSequence.Iterator(info)]
...
```

It takes only around 0.2 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

So after all of this, I decided to change up the method, and got another way for playing gifs. Just so you know it still prints out exceptions, so you can remove those few lines. Here is the code for anyone who needs it:

```
from pygame import mixer
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter.font as TkFont
from array import *
import time
import random
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
from itertools import count


MainMenu=Tk(className=" U-boot Sinker")
MainMenu.geometry("1600x900+150+75")
MainMenu.resizable(False,False)

images_list = []
def extract_image_from_gif(path):
    global gif_duration
    image= Image.open(path)
    for r in count(1):
        try:
            images_list.append(image.copy())
            image.seek(r)
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            break
    print(len(images_list))
x=0
def play_gif():
    global x, cur_img
    try:
        x+=1
        cur_img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(images_list[x])
        gif_lb.config(image=cur_img)
        MainMenu.after(10, play_gif)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        x=0
        MainMenu.after(10, play_gif)
        
gif_lb = Label(MainMenu)
gif_lb.pack()
extract_image_from_gif('StartScreen.gif')
play_gif()
MMCan=Canvas(MainMenu, width=1600, height=900)
MMCan.pack()

MainMenu.mainloop()
```

All in all thank you everyone that tried to help me, and lost braincells in process!